# Behavior of a React component passed as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In most cases, you pass down components to another component as `children`. But I've seen (for example in couple of UI libraries) that components can be passed using standard named `props` as well. I tried that too but I encountered couple of limitations and I wasn't able to find anything about that in the documentation (how it's actually supposed to work).

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
const App = ({ status, data }) => {
  return <Layout
    sidebar={<CustomSidebar />}
    toolbar={<CustomToolbar />}
    content={status == 'loading' ? <LoadingBar status={status} /> : <Content data={data} />}
  />
};

const LoadingBar = ({ status }) => <span>Loading... (current status: {status})</span>
```

As you can see here, using just `children` is not enough, I want to pass down multiple components and it will be `Layout'`s job to put them into right places. Obviously, the reason why I'm doing it this way is that I want to re-use the `Layout`.

But it doesn't work. The `LoadingBar` is correctly displayed but once the data is loaded (`status` changes from `loading` to `done`), the `LoadingBar` prints correctly the changed status (`done`) **but is never replaced by the `Content` component.** Actually, it should never print `done`, it should simply disappear.

I did some experiments and it only worked when I was passing completely static components as `props` (i. e. the *input* wasn't changing). This worked:

```
const App = ({ status, data }) => {
  return <Layout
    sidebar={<CustomSidebar />}
    toolbar={<CustomToolbar />}
    content={<ContentWrapper />}
  />
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => { ... };

const ContentWrapper = connect(mapStateToProps)(({ status, data }) => {
  return status == 'loading' ? <LoadingBar status={status} /> : <Content data={data} />;
});
```

As you can see, the `ContentWrapper` component is connected to `redux` store so it's updated completely independently on the parent's component.

Is there a way how to get the initial example working? Or am I doing something wrong? Is this approach endorsed?

**Edit:** The whole thing was a bug in my code. The `status` never changed to `done` and it didn't cross my mind to actually test it because of the overall weird behavior of this bug. See my answer bellow.

Comment: Also I think it would be best if you have status === 'loading' just to be sure. That's kind of the official equality check in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently the problem was in my code, there is nothing wrong with React and it works exactly as you would expect. I implemented the whole example on jsfiddle to test it in a separated environment so you can check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/9u4nmcrn/9/

It works like a charm.

---

To give a short explanation: In my real app, the `status` isn't a string, it's an object with two properites: `isLoading` (boolean indicating whether the request is in progress) and `done` (boolean indicating whether the request finished with success). The problem was that I was testing `done` in my outer component and `isLoading` in the `LoadingBar` (it hides itself once `isLoading` flips to false). For some other reason the boolean `done` never flipped to `true`. So as the result, the `LoadingBar` disappeared but it was never replaced with `Content` as `done` was still false. Unfortunately, I was from the very beginning convinced that there must be something wrong with React so I didn't do even the very basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In your initial example you're only passing one or the other of `<LoadingBar>` or `<Content>`. There's probably a bunch of variations of how to achieve what you want. One option would be to pass both of those elements as separate props and `status` as a prop and let `<Layout>` decide what to do with them. Or you could even do something like this if you want:

```js
content={function (status, data) {
  return status == 'loading' ? <LoadingBar /> : <Content data={data} />;
}}
```

Comment: I'm passing one or the other, but I'd expect that when the `status` changes, another component will be loaded. Regarding your first suggestion: `Layout` is a very general component. That kind of logic should be handled outside. Regarding your second suggestion: how is it supposed to work? How is this function going to get called?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I misread. So is `<App>` re-rendering when `status` updates? It seems like the problem must be there.

Comment: Okay, it works, the problem was with my code, not with React. I'll post an answer explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. Isn't it a state problem?

```
content={status === 'loading' ? <LoadingBar /> : <Content data={data} />}
```

Your LoadingBar will disappear when status is changed. Then 100% it will be replaced by the Content but with an empty data prop. I would say that the data prop doesn't get populated at the right time? What happens if you console log out the data prop when the loading bar disappears?

Is all of your state defined in a proper manner?

Comment: The `render` method of `Content` is never called. I try to throw an exception inside and it's never thrown. I used the Chrome Dev tools to inspect the rendered component hierarchy and the `LoadingBar` is actually still there but it's completely empty (just `<span />` inside).

Comment: What does you state have? If status is in the state then when changed it should force a page render then when going through content will display <Content data={data} />

Comment: You see in Redux it works because you are mapping the state to props and will force the page render.

Comment: When you say that the ContentWrapper component is connected to redux store you can somehow say that it is in the global state. Hence as that works I would say that your local state (on your react example) is not defined in the right manner.

Comment: Okay, I was misleading a bit (the `<span />` inside was actually in a way a correct behavior). I fixed the example. Now the `LoadingBar` prints the status. The point is that once the status changes to `done`, the loading bar should disappear, but it prints `done` instead. That means it's updated (and so is the parent component) but it never disappears.

Comment: Alright, problem was in my local state as you said :) I will post an answer explaining.